# Making a crash log meaningful (c++, Linux env)

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I have a compiled c++ application that produces a stack trace when it crashes.  At the moment, the stack trace isn't particularly meaningful.  I would like to process it so that it contains symbols, rather than addresses.

Does anyone have any pointers on how I might go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a map file its quite easy to map symbols to the addresses in the stack dump.
I wrote an article (including some sources) about this sometime ago at ddj:

http://www.drdobbs.com/tools/185300443

Answer (score 3):

Do you get a resolved stack dump if the program is compiled with `-g` or `-ggdb` and you don't strip the program?